# Multiple spaces in a string getting replaced with a single space in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-update

I executed a query like below.

```
update TABLE_NAME set COLUMNNAME='severity   =   100' where ID=10000
```

Here, 3 spaces are between `severity` and `=` and another 3 spaces between `=` and `100`.

After execution of the update query, `COLUMNNAME` of this `TABLE_NAME` got updated as `severity = 100`. Here, continuous spaces (3 spaces) of the database column is replaced with a single space.

But I want `COLUMNNAME` to be updated specifically as `'severity   =   100'` with 3 spaces to be retained between `severity` and `=` and another 3 spaces to be retained between `=` and `100`.

The java code which I am using to execute the query is :-

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("update TABLE_NAME set CRITICALTHRESHOLDVALUE=? where ID=?"); 
String criticalValue = "svSeverity   =   100";//This value is fetched from GUI.    
ps.setString(1,criticalValue);
ps.setInt(2,id);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please update the tags to include the RDBS you are using and the tool are you using to issue the update statement.

Comment: Tested this on sql-server, the 3 spaces remained there. Are you sure the value doesn't have the spaces removed when you fetched it from the GUI. Also are you really working with mysql, sql-server AND postgresql?